# Aurelia: Is there any option / decorator to restrict an attribute to a specific element

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

Hi I have created a custom element named as 'panel' and a custom attribute 'panel-type'. I want to restrict this 'panel-type' can be used only in 'panel' element. Is there any way to do that?

```
<panel value.bind='panel' panel-type='default'></panel>
```

--should work. But no other element can use 'panel-type'. like-

```
<some-other-tag panel-type='default'></some-other-tag>
```

--shouldn't work

Comment: What is your custom attribute doing? Can we see the code?

Comment: @thebluefox custom element is doing nothing specific. I just started learning aurelia. Its for my own knowledge

Comment: sounds like it's a over-kill to use custom attribute. `@bindable panelType` inside your panel component is enough for your use case. BYI, you can pass a pure string to a bindable just like what you did there.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code of your Custom Attribute - I can't tailor this to your specific needs - but it's easily possible;

In your Custom Attribute you have access to the the `Element` property - which is the physical element you've attached the attribute to. Therefore, you can simply use native JavaScript to get the elements tag name;

```
import {inject, LogManager} from "aurelia-framework";

@inject(Element)
export class panelTypeCustomAttribute {

    allowedElememt = false;

    constructor(Element) {
        this.element = Element;

        if(this.element.tagName == "PANEL") {
            this.allowedElement = true;
        } else {
            LogManager.getLogger('testCustomAttribute').warn("The panel-type custom attribute can only be used on <panel /> elements");
        }
    }

    foo() {
        // Then you can check for the allowedElement flag in any of your methods;
        if(this.allowedElement) {
            // Do your thing
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I am looking for a one line code. There could be some annotation.

Comment: "there could be some annotation"?

Comment: annotation like @restrict 'element-name' kind of. It could be great

Comment: Oh, you mean a decorator. To my knowledge - there isn't a decorator that does what you require. You can see the template decorators here; https://github.com/aurelia/templating/blob/master/src/decorators.js